# Find and replace text in a document

Tags: linux, sed

I am using the following:

```
sed 's/oldwebsite.com/newwebsite.com' file.sql
```

I got:

```
sed: -e expression #1 unterminated `s' command
```

Did I not correctly use sed?

EDIT:

Fixed with:

```
sed 's/oldwebsite.com/newwebsite.com/g' file.sql
```

Is there also a way to have it replace regardless of having text on either sides? Ran above and it did not replace any of the text.

Comment: Provide small sample of data from `file.sql`

Comment: Beware some characters act as metacharacters .e.g `.` matches any single character. To match a single period use `\.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `/` to end the replacement:

```
sed 's/oldwebsite.com/newwebsite.com/' file.sql
```

Add `g` (for global) after the last `/` if you want to replace all matches on the line, not just the first one.